# MVC ViewPageActivator and the view context

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a ViewPageActivator to set some properties on the view based on some properties of the model (PresentationModel if you are familiar with that term) at view creation time.  Unfortunately, the viewpage activator always gets the controller context, rather than the view context (see code below).  This means that the view page activator will get the wrong context when the view is a template, like an EditorTemplate.  Shouldn't the activator always get the viewContext?

```
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) {
        if (viewContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("viewContext");
        }

        object instance = null;

        Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(ViewPath);
        if (type != null) {
            instance = _viewPageActivator.Create(_controllerContext, type);
        }

        if (instance == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    MvcResources.CshtmlView_ViewCouldNotBeCreated,
                    ViewPath
                )
            );
        }

        RenderView(viewContext, writer, instance);
    }
```

Comment: can't u set model properties in controller?

Comment: Try using a custom view engine? You could override the Render method and pass in the correct context.